# Android : How can I tile a texture from a bitmap to a non-rectangular shape?

Tags: android, canvas

I am trying to draw non-rectangular shapes on canvas. I need to fill them up with textures like grass and tarmac(for roads). How can I do that? I have already tried to overlap bitmaps of different shapes to achieve this effect on one frame but the shapes keep changing as time progresses, so I need another solution.
Thanks in advance
Sameer Raina

Answer (score 0):

You can use BitmapDrawable to draw seamless pattern images like this

```
 BitmapDrawable tileImg = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.image);
 tileImg.setBounds(bounds);
 tileImg.setTileModeXY(TileMode.REPEAT, TileMode.REPEAT); 
 tileImg.draw(canvas); // this will fill the canvas.
```

To create shapes with it you should clip the canvas to a path that corresponds to your shape, and then calling the `tileImg.draw(canvas);` method, to fill the clipped area only.

Be careful though, because there are some issues with using `clipPath()`, read more about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972926/android-clippath-equivalent-for-hardware-accelerated-view) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8895677/work-around-canvas-clippath-that-is-not-supported-in-android-any-more/8895894#8895894)

Comment: I actually achieved the effect by using paint.setShader(BitmapShader).